# Error Instantiating Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, logcat

**I have fixed the problem, I checked my manifest file and it told me my activity was no longer concrete, I changed the class to abstract by mistake, changing it back from abstract fixed the error**

I have added in a interface in my app so I can edit a textEdit depending on a button click in the listview, The app was running fine until I added in this interface, now I get an error when I try run the app. I have searched the forums but can find th solution to my problem, hope somebody can help!

this is my main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pinchtapzoom.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapterInterface{

    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    public ListView list1;

    com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);

    //public EditText TotalCost;
    //public EditText TotalLitres;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);
        db.open();


        final MyAdapterInterface ad = new MyAdapterInterface() {
            @Override
            public void updateEditText(int value) {
                EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
                myEditText.setText(value);
            }
        };


        Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, addassignment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Delete.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button updateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Update.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Log.d("test", "customadapter is " + customAdapter.toString());
                //Log.d("test", "databaseHelper is " + databaseHelper.toString());
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, db.getAllRecords(), ad);
                list1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });




/*        @Override
        public void updateEditText(String value) {
            EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            myEditText.setText(value);
        }*/


    }

    private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        //private ArrayList<>

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            return null;
        }

    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }    
}
```

This is my Adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.pinchtapzoom.R;


public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public int counter = 0;
    private MyAdapterInterface mMyInterface;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, MyAdapterInterface myInterface) {

        super(context, c);
        this.context = context;
        this.mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
    Context context;


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views
        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

        final EditText edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);

        Button plusButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                mMyInterface.updateEditText(counter);
            }
        });

        final Button minusButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                edit1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                mMyInterface.updateEditText(counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my interface

```
public interface MyAdapterInterface {

    public void updateEditText(int value);
}
```

And this is the logcat error I am getting

```
    Process: com.example.rory.dbtest, PID: 10950
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.rory.dbtest/com.example.rory.dbtest.MyActivity}:   java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.rory.dbtest.MyActivity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class     com.example.rory.dbtest.MyActivity
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final MyAdapterInterface ad = new MyAdapterInterface() {
            @Override
            public void updateEditText(int value) {
                EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
                myEditText.setText(value);
            }
        };
```

shouldn't take place inside your onCreate() method, but somewhere else in the class, as a normal method. And it should be written like that :

```
public void updateEditText(int value) {
      EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
      myEditText.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this didnt work im still getting the same error when it runs

Comment: On some furthing reading I have discovered that in my manifest file that the main app activity has an error, It says that the class is no longer concrete, do you know how to solve this?